# Is there a way to display audio bitrate in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, audio

I want to have a quick and easy way to check bitrate of compressed audio files, without having to open iTunes/Quicktime etc.

Either a Finder option (Get info/Inspector/List view) or perhaps an AppleScript via Right click > Service would do, via output to Terminal or system pop-up.

Are there any established solutions out there, or will we have to look at a scripting solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could fashion a service in Automator using the Terminal.app and your shell with something like:

```
mdls -name kMDItemTotalBitRate file
```

Comment: Tried to get it running as an Automator Service using Applescript, but couldn't get it to output the result to a message box/terminal. Looking for advice on this.

Comment: @Winterflags Sorry, I'm not an applescripter but I think you would set a variable to the results of `do shell script mdls .....`  and then display the variable in a dialog box.